# Generate LINQ or Lambda Expression for Multiple columns based on the user selection of checkboxes

Tags: c#

I have a few checkboxes on top of my webpage which correspond to the columns of my Table. Like there is a column studentId then there will be a checkbox studentId and so on. I want to write such a linq/lamda expression for List which will filter the on the basis of the checkboxes selected. For example if selects studentId and studentType checkbox then linq/lambda expression should bring all the rows matching the selection.

example:

If studentId and studentType checked then:

```
foreach (Child c in SomeList)
{
if (chkStudentId.checked)
{
 List.FindAll (h=> h.StudentId == c.studentId);
}
if (chkStudentType.checked)
{
 List.FindAll (h => h.StudentType == c.studentType)
}
}
}
```

I can't figure out how am I going to write such a code that if user selects multiple checkboxes, the query should compare to all the columns and bring the values based only on the checkboxes checked. The above is only static and does not help. please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expression trees are a great help if you want your query to be totally dynamic. But if the number of checkboxes is static you can also choose for the following solution:

```
var students = <your list of students>.AsQueryable();

if ( chkStudentId.checked)
{
    students = students.Where(s => s.StudentId == c.StudentId);
}

if (chkStudentType.checked))
{
    students = students.Where(s => s.StudentType== h.StudentType);
}
```

In such a way you can combine the where clauses in a dynamic way.

Comment: I have just tried this. When I debug and look at the results from the where clause, the list is empty and says "Does not yeild results" on expanding. Any idea?

Comment: Is there student data before you start filtering? Have you checked which filter doesn't match any items? Or do you want the filter to be an OR instead of AND filter?

Comment: Yes, there is student data before filtering, and I verified that after casting my list AsQueryable the students list has data. However after this line no result is yielded: students = students.Where(s => s.StudentId == c.StudentId);

Comment: Can you manually verify that there are items which satisfy your filter? What are the types of StudentId and StudentType?

Comment: Thanks for your timely responses. The problem was with my foreach loop and the values were not matching. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I'm fairly new to this and there is probably much better ways to do this. Any feedback is higlhy appreciated.*

Note that this method has no error/null checking. Since it uses reflection, you should profile it if you plan to use it in production.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Filter<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection, Dictionary<string, object> filters) {
    var type = typeof (T);
    var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var queryable = collection.AsQueryable();
    var instance = Expression.Parameter(type, "instance");

    var expressions = new Stack<Expression>();

    foreach (var filter in filters) {
        var propertyName = filter.Key;
        var property = properties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == propertyName);
        if (property == null)
            continue;

        var left = Expression.Property(instance, property);
        var right = Expression.Constant(filter.Value, property.PropertyType);
        var expr = Expression.Equal(left, right);

        expressions.Push(expr);
    }

    Expression call = null;
    Expression previousExpression = null;
    while(expressions.Count > 0) {
        var expr = expressions.Pop();
        if(previousExpression == null) {
            previousExpression = expr;
            call = expr;
        } else {
            var and = Expression.AndAlso(previousExpression, expr);
            call = and;
            previousExpression = and;
        }
    }

    var whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        "Where",
        new[] { queryable.ElementType },
        queryable.Expression,
        Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(call, new[] { instance }));

    return queryable.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(whereCallExpression);
}
```

It overates all filters and tries to find a matching property. If it does find a property, it creates a EqualExpression which compares the actual value and the value you want to filter by. It then creates a `MethodCallExpression` which is passed to the query provider.

Theese expressions are then combined. I think the part with the stack is wrong, and that there is a better way to do it.

Usage:

```
var persons = new List<Person> {new Person {Name = "Alex", Age = 22}, new Person {Name = "Jesper", Age = 30}};
var filters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
filters.Add("Name", "Alexander Nyquist");

var results = Filter(persons, filters);
```

Since it's building expressions, it does works with Linq 2 Sql (tested) and probably Entity Framework. Linq 2 sql produces the following query:

```
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[Name], [t0].[Email]
FROM [dbo].[Persons] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Name] = @p0
-- @p0: Input VarChar (Size = 8000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Alexander Nyquist]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 4.0.30319.1
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

From your description of your problem it seemed fairly straight forward that you have a list of predicates, that are enabled or disable based on the check boxes, and then you want to aggregate them to create a single composite filter. Easy!

Your predicates look like this:

```
h => h.StudentId == c.studentId
h => h.StudentType == c.studentType
```

But because of the check boxes, you really want them to look like this:

```
h => chkStudentId.Checked ? h.StudentId == c.studentId : true
h => chkStudentId.Checked ? h.StudentType == c.studentType : true
```

You're effectively extending the predicates to include the check box. Here's a function that does that:

```
Func<CheckBox, Func<Student, bool>, Func<Student, bool>> extend =
    (cb, p) =>
        s => cb.Checked ? p(s) : true;
```

Now you can write your list of predicates like this:

```
var predicates = new Func<Student, bool>[]
{
    extend(chkStudentId, h => h.StudentId == c.studentId),
    extend(chkStudentType, h => h.StudentType == c.studentType),
    // etc
};
```

Next LINQ has an easy way to turn a list of somethings into a single something:

```
Func<Student, bool>
    predicate =
        predicates.Aggregate((a, p) => s => a(s) && p(s));
```

Now you just have to execute this code to get your filtered list:

```
var filtered = SomeList.Where(predicate);
```

Now anytime any of the check boxes change you just need to enumerate the `filtered` collection and you'll get your filtered results.

Comment: Thank you! An answer that required some thinking (esp. the aggregate part), but for sure helped me out more than all the others I found (not just here) and ultimately enabled me to derive a fully dynamic solution for my specific needs that I am very satisfied with and that performs well! So, if you're willing to do more than just copy&paste, this is the best answer!

Answer (score 0):

Expression Trees can do what you want, but they are rather complicated.  They allow you to dynamically build the linq query.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

The Dynamic Linq Library may also be of use.  I haven't personally used it though.
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was a bit modification of what Wouter de Kort
suggest and was like this:

```
    var students = StudentList.AsQueryable();  

        foreach (Student sc in GroupingList)
        {  
           students = students.Where(s => (chkStudentId.Checked? h.StudentId.Trim() == sc.StudentId.Trim() : true) && (chkStudentType.Checked? h.StudentType.Trim() == sc.StudentType.Trim() : true) );
 }
```